# Is "lightening up" a request I need to comply with at work?

Tags: work-environment

My direct supervisor has been distant and indifferent towards me since my recent, valid request for PTO. My request was denied, but I was lied to about the reason.

So my attitude at work has been nothing but straight to the point and serious. I don't joke around anymore, and don't go the extra mile either. Since changing my attitude, I've been told that i need to "lighten up."

As long as I complete my tasks at work without error, do I need to change my now-serious demeanor?

Comment: Does the PTO have anything to do with this? Seems like a separate issue.

Comment: So, you didn't get your PTO approved (for whatever reason), and now you're pouting about it. It's understandable to be disappointed and frustrated for a time, but pouting for more than just a couple of days and turning it into a grudge is childish (and unprofessional).

Comment: How is being serious equate to holding a grudge? I fail to see your logic in have a 'straight to the point' attitude while at work?

Comment: it equates to holding a grudge because you're doing it as a consequence of feeling wronged, so that's what it is.

Comment: No, it was a blatent lie. I was told that my direct supervisor and dept. Director would be out of the office for a meeting. I found there schedule on a table in the breakroom and it was 2 weeks after the date i asked for my PTO. Furthermore, was explicitly told that was the reason. Then on the specific date of in question. I come into work and they are in the office. When asked why they were there, they said that 'they* never *said* they woould be out of the office'.

Comment: That wouldn't matter to your question about being serious unless your seriousness is caused by that event. (*which some would call a grudge if you do it indefinitely*) Imagine if you continued being serious and 5 years from now someone asks you, "Why so serious?" You turn to them and say, "My manager (lied to me/denied me PTO once)" - That is a grudge.

Comment: @DigitalFire Being unable to trust your superiors is certainly enough to justify leaving if you decide to do that. Just a word of caution, their unprofessional behavior does not justify any unprofessional behavior on your part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep a positive attitude. It's better for your health and mental state. There could easily be something stressful in either your, or your supervisors life that is changing their point of view temporarily.

Re-examine your attitude before the supervisors change of attitude, perhaps you had been becoming complacent and unknowingly lowering your quality of work.

Being serious is not a problem, as long as it isn't code for being difficult, uncooperative, or unfriendly. They aren't paying you too laugh and joke, but no one wants to work with someone that makes everyone around them miserable.

Answer (score 7):

You complete your tasks, but people are not comfortable with you. Should completing the tasks be the only thing that matters?

Yes, but only if it is the tasks that cut your paychecks and not the people you work for and who approve your paychecks.

No professional is considered successful on the job if they don't perform their tasks AND they don't work well with their colleagues and management. You are making your supervisor uncomfortable, and your supervisor is signaling to you that they are having a harder time working with you.

It's up to you to determine whether you should comply with their request to lighten up.

Find yourself another way to express your displeasure.

Answer (score 3):

Its not nice, but denying PTO is usually done for valid reasons and no one likes doing that.

Whether the reason given is a lie or not is beside the point as far as validity is concerned. Unless you know your employer has gratuitously denied your PTO on purpose to make you miserable, you should assume that there are good reasons for the denial and understand that sometimes everything is not according to the employee handbook.

You are making things worse by reacting in a negative way to a decision that was probably hard to make in the first place. "Lighten up" means "get over it".

That said, the damage is done. You might redeem yourself by apologizing and coming to an agreement on an alternative PTO date.

Comment: Actually, I closed a contract through my own company and don't need to work for someone else.